# How can I configure team city to build latest version only instead of each commit

Tags: teamcity, continuous-deployment

I am using teamcity 8.0 with github.

I have a continuous deployment build configuration set up to look at our master branch and when changes occur they are built and deployed.

When code is ready for deployment it is merged in from another branch into master, so master is always a snapshot of the last deployed code. ongoing development happens on other branches.

The problem we have is that when we deploy there is usually at least 20 commits and often many more from a mix of developers.  Team city builds and deploys each commit separately which takes an age and leaves our live system unusable while this is occurring.

Is there a way to configure team city to just build the most recent code when it detects a change instead of every individual commit

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Review your VCS trigger settings. "Per-checkin Triggering" should be turned off.
Also, check if you are using GitHub Service hook for "TeamCity" - it may also produce number of builds.